# search the word and have any integer from 0-9 at the end of that word by using fgrep command in linux

Tags: linux, filter, expression, wildcard

command to search the word Good or good and have any integer from 0-9 at the end of that word by using fgrep command in linux

anyone answer my Question It will be very Helpful

Answer (score 0):

For example here is input:

```
GOod11 luck, good0 luck,
Good5555 luck in your new bed
Enjoy your nightmares, Honey,
When you're resting your head
```

Here is my assumptions:

- For output matched expression words only, use `-o` flag, `grep -Ewo '[Gg]ood[0-9]*' input.txt`, result:

  ```
  good0
  Good5555
  ```
- For printing full lines with matched expression use `grep -Ew '[Gg]ood[0-9]*' input.txt`, result:

  ```
  GOod11 luck, good0 luck,
  Good5555 luck in your new bed
  ```

  *PS*: Append flag `-n` for adding print line numbers.
- If you want ignore case in any character, use `-i` flag, `grep -Eowi 'good[0-9]*' input.txt`, result:

  ```
  GOod11
  good0
  Good5555
  ```